# Exponential sum over polynomial values

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

Let $f(x)=a_{k}x^{k}+\dots+a_{1}x+a_{0}\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ with $a_{k}>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large. I would like to know an estimate of the following sum:

$$\sum_{N\leq n\leq 2N}\exp(\alpha f(n)),$$
when $N^{-kc}\leq |\alpha|\leq N^{kC},$ where $0<c<1$ and $C>0$ (here $\exp(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$).

I know that Vinogradov's result cannot apply in this case, because we don't have control on the Diophantine approximations of $\alpha$.
I tried to apply the Van der Corput's method, but the estimate is quite weak.

Does anyone know some refences on this problem?

Comment: What conditions on $\alpha$ and $f(x)$ rule out the possibility that $\alpha f(n)$ is $2 \pi i k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$?

Comment: The above are the only hypothesis on $\alpha$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: Moreover, if the polynomial $\alpha f(x)$ assumes $k+1$ integer values, then it will have rational coefficients, but this is not possible.

Comment: Are $k$ and the $a_k$ fixed or varying with $N$?

Comment: Montgomery's "Ten Lectures on the Interface Between Analytic Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis" is a great reference.

Comment: $k,a_{j}$ with $j=1,...,k$ are fixed.

Comment: I suppose "estimate" means "upper bound for the absolute value". Do you want a result which is uniform in $\alpha$? This will not be possible. Also, as far as I see $\alpha=1$ is in your admissible range - for that the sum is of maximal size, so the only general upper bound is $N$.

Comment: I think that the case $\alpha=1$ is unimportant here, because $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. Anyway, I convinced myself that the problem has no solution, since when $\alpha$ varies into an interval then the probability that the sum is near a peak is quite high.